# Superposition of two images with different top and left values

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, css-selectors

I would like to ask how do we basically put an image over another image but not at the same coordinates using CSS in a same container . I have tried this:

HTML:

```
<div class="tisane">
            <img id="2" src="images/herbal-tea-cup-png-images-35.png" alt="Tasse d'infusion de millepertuis" style="z-index: 2;"/>
            <img id="1" src="images/noirairbrush.png" alt="" style="z-index: 1;">
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.tisane {
      display: inline-flex;

  }

  .tisane img #2 {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 140px;
  }
   .tisane img #1 {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 130px;

    
 }
```

Here was the result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Basically, the images have completely left the frame for some reason, and I've only changed like, five pixels for the new image (airbrushnoix.png). Everything was placed fine before I had changed the top and left values.

Comment: Basically I want the image airbrush to be below the image cup of tea, but I don't want them to be exactly at the same top: and left: values

Answer (score 1):

First Don't start an ID's with a digit. Because it won’t work. Class identifiers are allowed to start with a number, but ID identifiers are not. So that's basically your issue. Instead do something like this `.tisane img#img1 { ... }`

Try this

```css
.tisane {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
}

.tisane img#img2 {
  top: 80px;
  left: 0px;
}

.tisane img#img1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 130px;
}

.tisane img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 220px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="tisane">
  <img id="img1" src="https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/ios/932332871/edd30e1f8a35bdfdd85c921fe1a6c616?v=1" />
  <img id="img2" src="https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/b0c73f50f74400e6458644eac56fa9f5.jpg" />
</div>
```